# Filebeat cannot use custom variable in filebeat.yml

Tags: filebeat

#### This is conent of my filebeat.yml

```
queue:
  mem:
    events: 204800
    flush.min_events: 102400
    flush.timeout: 1s
filebeat.idle_timeout: 1s
filebeat.inputs:
- type: container
  ignore_older: 24h
  scan_frequency: 1s
  close_inactive: 1m
  max_bytes: 10485760 
  enabled: true
  stream: all
  paths:
    - "/var/log/containers/*.log"
  fields:
    source: business
  processors:
  - add_kubernetes_metadata:
      in_cluster: true
      host: ${NODE_NAME}
      matchers:
        - logs_path:
            logs_path: "/var/log/containers/"
      add_resource_metadata:
        deployment: true
output.file:
  path: '/tmp/%{[kubernetes.namespace]}'
  filename:  "filebeat-%{[kubernetes.deployment.name]}-%{[kubernetes.pod.name]}"
```

The effect I want is that filebeat recognizes the fields of the kubernetes log.
I tried `{}` and `%{[]}`,but these metods can't Come into force.
I hope it can recognize  `%{[kubernetes.namespace]}` .

Comment: What about using the marchers field? What do you mean recognize?